# How can I utilize Drupal hooks for altering and validating forms in place of CiviCRM hooks?

Tags: drupal, hooks

My website is built on Drupal, and I prefer using Drupal hooks over CiviCRM hooks for modifying and validating forms, as I find Drupal modules easier to create and their hooks more user-friendly. However, when I follow the standard Drupal alter process, such as employing hook_form_alter and using krumo($form_id) to print out and identify the form's ID, I am unable to obtain any output for CiviCRM forms.

Is it possible to use Drupal hooks instead of CiviCRM hooks for this purpose?
I would greatly appreciate any assistance that anyone can provide. Thank you very much.

Comment: what sort of 'civicrm forms' are you dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

The forms themselves aren't drupal forms so drupal hooks won't do anything, but you *can* put civi hook implementations in a drupal module, if you prefer using drupal modules over civi extensions.

Note there is a caching/bootstrap bug where the civi hooks won't get called from a drupal module if running via command line, but they work in the UI.